# tvOS App to Show PPT?

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

I have an existing iOS app that has one feature for mostly displaying a list of PPT files, and then viewing those within a UIWebView.  What are some recommendations for going about creating a new target for the tvOS, since it doesn't have a UIWebView?

Comment: @C_X So, in your opinion, a DropBox app on the new apple tv would be pointless, because it mostly displays files?  Even though that would be a most sought after app to view all PDFs and any other such files on a huge tv screen at any time?

Comment: I am not saying its pointless i would love it if I will get one... But with current TVOS I think its difficult to show ppt or pdf files ad all what we use for this purpose in iOS is not available in TVOS, unless you create some custom component for that or apple add support for this

Comment: If you want to go all out and are feeling ambitious, you could try to make your own web engine for tvOS, since WebKit is not a part of tvOS. It would probably end up feeling a lot like the Web Browser on the PS3, which is likely why Apple removed it in the first place, but it's an idea.